# facebook activity feed expires every day

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-social-plugins, access-token

We have a facebook activity feed on our homepage http://www.tvsyd.dk/seerneviser that used to work fine, but recently we got some problems.

The content in the feed disappears.

When I go to Graph API Explorer to get a new acces token, it works fine for approximately 24 hours. But then the content in the feed disappears again and again.

How do we make the feed work again?

Best regards - Bjoern

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an expiring access token. Be sure to request an access token with the offline_access permission to get one that won't expire based on time.

You may check the [Extended Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions) reference for more information on various permissions.